# Dual monitors - move system tray to right-most end of taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, multiple-monitors, ultramon

I'm using dual monitors with Windows 7 (and Ultramon). Is there any way to move the system tray to the right end of the taskbar on my right-most monitor?

So rather than:

```
Start|<Pinned Programs><Open Programs><etc>|System Tray|<Open programs on monitor #2>
```

I would have:

```
Start|<Pinned Programs><Open Programs><Open programs on monitor #2>|System Tray
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the multi displays in Windows 7 the taskbar is only viewable on one monitor.

Using UltraMon's 'Smart Taskbar' you gain the 'Open programs on monitor #2' style taskbar. There is no mention within UltraMon of moving the Start button or System Tray to this toolbar, 'Mirroring' won't give you what you desire (ie 2 work areas, 2 start menu's and/or 2 system tray's).

I'm not aware of any other way of seperating them to different displays.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [multi -mon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm)?  It has free trial version. I don't user it window 7, but in windows XP it does produce a taskbar on the the 2nd monitor.   Also only the windows that are open on the respective monitor are listed in its own task bar.

**Update**: Upon re-reading your question, I do now understand that my answer did *not* fit your needs. Also, Multi-Mon will not fit your needs, as it has no control over the location of your system tray.

Comment: Multi-mon just gives the user the same features as UltraMon's 'Smart Taskbar'.